# Use Guava CacheBuilder correctly

Tags: java, guava, google-guava-cache

Could somebody explain me please how to use the Guava CacheBuilder correctly.

Should getFromNetwork() raise an exception or return null, if the data is not reachable? Should I raise the Execution Exception and use guavaCache.get(). I am just not sure what the documentation means with unchecked exceptions?

Do I use the CacheBuilder as is it supposed to be used?
I dont use guavaCache.put()? this is done automatically. right?

```
        guavaCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(maxCapacity)
            .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .removalListener(new RemovalListener<Object, Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<Object, Object> notification) {}
            })
            .build(
                    new CacheLoader<String, byte[]>() {
                        public byte[] load(String key) throws Exception {
                            return getFromNetwork(key);
                        }
                    });

private byte[] get(Object... params) {
    String url = paramsToUri(params).toString();

    byte[] data = null;
    data = guavaCache.get(url); //?
    data = guavaCache.getUnchecked(url); //?
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [Javadoc for `load`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#load(K)) is quite clear:

> Returns:
>      the value associated with key; must not be null
>   Throws:
>       Exception - if unable to load the result

If the data is not reachable, you are unable to load the result, so throw an Exception.

> Do I use the CacheBuilder as is it supposed to be used? I dont use guavaCache.put()? this is done automatically. right?

Yes, this looks fine to me, although you only need to call one of `get` or `getUnchecked`. You definitely don't need to `put`.